# Send PDF's using Multipeer Connectivity in swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, multipeer-connectivity

I have found an implementation of sending PDF's using Multipeer Connectivity in Objective C at the following link.

[Multipeer Connectivity : Share Files to all peers simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27184493/multipeer-connectivity-share-files-to-all-peers-simultaneously?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I was wondering if anyone could provided a swift implementation for sharing PDFs via Multipeer Connectivity?

In my implementation, I am trying to send the files via the `send(data: Data, toPeers: [MCPeerID], with: MCSessionSendDataMode)` method. Is it possible to type cast the PDF to type `Data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a week I have figured out that it is possible to represent a pdf as type data by using the `dataRepresentation()` method. Using this and the `send(data: Data, toPeers: [MCPeerID], with: MCSessionSendDataMode)` method, PDF's can be sent using multiplier connectivity.

**Example Code**

```
import PDFKit
import MultipeerConnectivity

let pdfDocument: PDFDocument? = PDFDocument(url: yourURLToPDFDocument)
let session: MCSession = MCSession(peer: yourPeerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: .required)

if let pdfData = pdfDocument?.dataRepresentation() {
    try session.send(pdfData, toPeers: yourArrayOfPeers, with: .reliable)
}
```